# Computation of cohomology with ideal sheaf involved.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a complex projective surface an $Z\subset X$ be a finite set of points (reduced closed subscheme of dimension zero).

Denote by $\mathcal{I}_Z$ the ideal sheaf of $Z$. Let $E$ be a vector bundle over $X$.

**Under which conditions does the cohomology group 
$$
\mbox{H}^1(X,E\otimes\mathcal{I}_Z)
$$
vanish?**

I am aware of some results for $E$ a line bundle but none in higher rank. Any reference will be appreciated.

**Added:** We have the long exact sequence
$$
0 \to \mbox{H}^0(X,E\otimes\mathcal{I}_Z) \to \mbox{H}^0(X,E) \to \mbox{H}^0(Z,E|_Z) \to \mbox{H}^1(X,E\otimes\mathcal{I}_Z) \to \mbox{H}^1(X,E) \to 0
$$
and the vanishing of $\mbox{H}^1(X,E\otimes\mathcal{I}_Z)$ implies the vanishing of $\mbox{H}^1(X,E)$. Thus $\mbox{H}^1(X,E) = \{0\}$ is a necessary condition. **What can be imposed to $E$ for this condition also be sufficient?**

**The case that interests me is when $E$ has rank two and $Z$ is the zero  scheme of a global section of $E$. Hence $h^0(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z) = c_2(E)$.**

Comment: It vanishes if the map $H^0(E) \to H^0(E\vert_Z)$ is surjective and the map $H^1(E) \to H^1(E\vert_Z)$ is injective.

Comment: @Sasha This surjectivity and injectivity is what I want with the vanishing...

Comment: Which is your surface and do you know anything about $c_1(E)$?

Comment: @Sasha I'm trying to calculate this for $X$ a ruled surface over a curve of genus $g$ with invariant $e$  and $E= TX\otimes L $ where $L$ is numerically equivalent to $(n + 2g-2)f$, $f$ the class of a fiber and $n>0$. Hence $c_2(E) = 2n$ and 
$c_1(E) = 2C_0 + (2n+e-2g-2)f$ where $C_0$ is a minimal section, $C_o^2 = -e$.

Comment: I'd like to know how to work with these cohomologies in general but I'll be happy to know what happens in this particular case.

Comment: Assume $X = P_C(F)$, where $F$ is a rank-2 vector bundle. Then there is an exact sequence $H^0(T_C \otimes L) \to H^1(ad(F) \otimes L) \to H^1(X,E) \to H^1(T_C \otimes L) \to 0$, where $L$ is considered as a line bundle on $C$ of degree $2g - 2 + n$ and $ad(F) = (F \otimes F^*)/O_C$. The first map is induced by the Attiyah class of $F$. Using it, you can compute $H^1(X,E)$ if you have some control over $F$ and $L$.

Comment: @Sasha And in this case the vanishing of $\mbox{H}^1(X,E)$ implies the vanishing of $\mbox{H}^1(X,E\otimes \mathcal{I}_Z)$ ?

Comment: To control $H^1(X,E \otimes I_Z)$ you can use the Koszul resolution $0 \to \det(E) \to E \to E \otimes I_Z \to 0$ and the corresponding exact sequence of cohomology.

Comment: @Sasha could you elaborate how we get this resolution? I've already tried the Eagon-Northcott resolution of $\mathcal{O}_Z$ and this led me nowhere.

Comment: The Koszul complex in this case is $0 \to \det(E^\vee) \to E^\vee \to \mathcal{I}_Z \to 0$, right?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. But you can tensor the Koszul resolution by $E$ to get $0 \to E \otimes \det(E^\vee) \to E \otimes E^\vee \to E \otimes I_Z \to 0$ and describe the cohomology of the first two terms in an analogous way to the description of the cohomology of $E$.

Comment: $E \otimes \det(E^\vee) = E^\vee$  and its cohomology is easy to compute. Then it goes back to calculating the cohomology of $E^\vee \otimes E = End(TX)$.